# mqtt client on beaglebone

Tags: debian, mqtt, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

Someone has ported o runned some `mqtt-client` for longterm running on `BeagleBone black`?
I'm in the start phases, and I'm searching for the right,(easiest) way to have some `mqtt client` on this device.

I'm looking trought 3 way:

1. Starting with Debian on Beaglebone and using `std pkg` on this distro
2. Porting a cool and stable library like `eclipse-paho` on `angstrom distro`
3. Using `node.js mqtt client` on the default enviroment

Some suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I've built mosquito and it's tools in the beaglebone black, they all work fine

Comment: Today i've build mosquitto client from the source

Comment: This blog discusses using Paho and other clients on the beaglebone: http://floriansblog.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's more - far more - than just an MQTT client, but have you seen [nodeRed](http://nodered.org/)? A visual programming environment for Node.js, designed for 'wiring the Internet of Things'. It runs fine on my BBB, and talks happily to mosquitto running on the same platform.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Paho, mosquitto, HiveMQ would all be great ways to run MQTT on a beaglebone. You want something with the smallest footprint, since it's a small device with decent RAM/processing power.

If you're running your Beaglebone on Debian, I really recommend using mosquitto - they have their own Debian repositories, and mosquitto is a really great open source, simple way to implement MQTT. You can find links here or with a simple google search.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-the-mosquitto-mqtt-messaging-broker-on-debian-8

https://mosquitto.org/download/
https://mosquitto.org/2013/01/mosquitto-debian-repository/

Examples:
http://docs.gadgetkeeper.com/display/docs/Realtime+temperature+monitoring+with+BeagleBone+Black+and+MQTT+protocol

http://www.microdev.it/wp/en/2017/03/12/mqtt-with-beaglebone-and-esp8266-mosquitto-installation-on-beaglebone/